# Printing out links from a site using PHP web crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have made this code for printing links in a given url/site. But unfortunately it prints them as text instead of anchor links.

so far this code works as printing links as text::

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.sitename.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
foreach($html->find("a") as $link) {
    echo $url.$link->href."<br/>";
}
?>
```

while i tried this, to prints them a anchor links but it prints blank page (not even a error)

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.sitename.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
foreach($html->find("a") as $link){
    echo "<a href='".$url.$link->href."'>"."</a>"."<br/>";
}
?>
```

And also , I was wondering how to extracts only links from particular area (div element) instead of whole page?

Any Help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: You got use domDocument and then you can get that done.. simple html is good but not very good

Comment: can you guide me a little bit about it.

Comment: Try googling DOMDocument in Php

Comment: so, should i be changing the very line that prints out the link into DOM?

Comment: It is the base model on which simple html dom is made which you are currently using ... SO yes you won't need this any more

Comment: so, what should i do?

Comment: Google Google  and Google

Comment: dude, please .. that one line.. can;t give it to me.. i  swear i'll learn before i apply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134767/discussion-between-m-a-siddiqui-and-harish-kolliparat).